# style isolation in docusaurus

Tags: styles, docusaurus, isolation

docusaurus is a very useful tool, I love it, we are creating our own component library, the demo of the component library, and eventually rendering in docusaurus, but I found a problem, some of the global styles of docusaurus's own themes affect the React components in the demo. Is there any good advice or elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a problem indeed - even creating an iframe, the styles are being overridden globally.